# How to use two types of models in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, types, models

I only have one model, but I want to use it 2 times in different ways in my View.

```
@model IEnumerable<JChatAdmin.Models.CityCountryModel.**CityCountryModel**>
```

@model JChatAdmin.Models.CityCountryModel.**CityCountryModel**

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to create a new class with with a property for each "submodel" you would like to use and use that new class as the model:

```
namespace JChatAdmin.Models.CityCountryModel
{
    public class CombinedCityCountryModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CityCountryModel> EnumerableCountryModel { get; set; }
        public CityCountryModel SingleCountryModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your model would then be:

```
@model JChatAdmin.Models.CityCountryModel.CombinedCityCountryModel
```